# What do you call that oppressive feeling you get when it's hot and muggy?

Tags: single-word-requests

When it's hot and humid, you start to feel slightly uncomfortable, where you're not just "hot", but also a bit dizzy, lightheaded, nauseous, and you feel like you can't breathe. What is that feeling called?

Now maybe you can just simply call it "oppressive" and "uncomfortable", but is there a more specific term to it?

Comment: ["The night was hot, wait no, the night, the night was humid. The night was humid, no wait, hot, hot. The night was hot. The night was hot and wet, wet and hot. That’s humid. The night was humid. The night was dry, yet it was raining."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4c1sgug6prw)

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a ***suffocating*** feeling.

Cambridge:

> **[suffocating](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/suffocating)**
> *adjective* ​
> *informal*
>
> Something that is suffocating makes you feel uncomfortably hot or unable to breathe:
> *I've got to open the window - it's
> suffocating in here!
>
> suffocating smoke/fumes*